# python edit file by every line to have only several indexes

Tags: python-2.7

I am beginner in python. We have installed on AIX machine python2. I need to edit file contains 48 characters and have only index 14-18.

I am trying to do it, but not success till now. This is not working:

```
import os

fin = open("list","w")

lines = fin.readlines()
for line in lines:
        line = line[14:19:1]
fin.close
```

Comment: read the whole file (line by line), modify the content, and then write the whole file back. This is the simplest approach and it should work fine unless the file is very big.

Comment: `open("list","w")` opens the file output, so you are clearing the file when you open it.

Comment: @OP You either want to select a line-range from the file, or select a column-range from the file, or filter some lines depending the content, or something else -- I cann't tell from the given information.